# Pulling data from RedPrarie client using VBA

Tags: excel, odbc, adodb, vba

I'm trying to automate certain processes at my work. They are currently using RedPrarie Client

I already know how to pull data from an sql table using VBA ADODB and ODBC connection. But integrating this with RedPrarie seems to be a grey topic.

Can anyone shed some light on this topic?

Comment: What do you mean by integrating? Submitting data? Pulling table connections? Submitting data directly is not recommended in any case, submit it through an import form, then have it imported to the RedPrarie in the native environment. Use blueprints and documentation for table connections.

Comment: Pulling data from tables specifically. I wanted to avoid the click click click GUI provided by the RedPrarie client. I wanted to automate the communication between RedPrarie and other applications within the project using VBA/VBS as the middleware

Comment: Then you set the ODBC connection and just refresh. Correct me if I'm wrong but it's backed by an SQL server thus will service your data connection and data table.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I will need to try this out 15 days from now. I will update you on what will happen if I try. Thanks